# Matrix-vector-multiplication with tensors in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy.array `A` with shape `(l,l)` and another numpy.array `B` with shape `(l,m,n)`. Usually, the second and third dimension in `B` correspond to spatial cells and the first to something else.

I want to compute

```py
l,m,n = 2,3,4                 # dummy dimensions
A = np.random.rand(l,l)       # dummy data
B = np.random.rand(l,m,n)     # dummy data
C = np.zeros((l,m,n))


for i in range(m):
  for j in range(n):
    C[:,i,j] = A@B[:,i,j]
```

i.e., in every spatial cell, I want to perform a matrix-vector-multiplication.
Since I have to do this frequently, I would like to know, if there's a more compact way to write this with `numpy`. (Especially, because there are several situations in which the tensor has shape `(l,m,n,o,p)`.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using `np.einsum`:

```py
np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A,B)
```

Explanation:
Einstein notation implies that we sum over matching subscripts.

```py
np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A,B)
= rewritten in math terms
A_{i,j} B_{j,k,l}
= Einstein notation implies summation
sum_j A_{i,j} B_{j,k,l}
```